# Tableview cell make dynamic editing style change

Tags: swift, uitableview, styles, editing

I'm trying to do tableview cell editing style to be able to change from "insert" to "delete" status once new cells added as in the attached picture.
I know how to make either "insert" or "delete" style, but don't know how to make them dynamically changing.
Would appreciate any ideas and help.
[image: How should it looklike]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find the solution and can close this request. Hopefully it would help anyone.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    if tableView.isEditing {
        if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows (inSection: 0) - 1) {
               return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.insert
        } else {
               return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
        }
    } else {
           return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    }}
```